# Return the max value in a new column for each repeating value in the other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

*Background*: I was hoping to generate a new column named: datasample based on another column named: end_bin from a table.

*Question:* Is there a way to return the max value in each row of the new column if the value is repeated in the previous column.

*Expected result:*

| end_bin | datasample |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

I couldnt find a method to do this in pandas, any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Can you explin your ouput? Why is first value `1` ?

Comment: So the first value is simply the number of occurances of that value in end_bin. i.e 6 occured just once in end_bin and so did others except 2 which occured 3 times in total across end_bin. Hence 3 is displayed across all rows with corresponding value as 2.

Comment: I hope this is what you are looking for.

    _df = pd.DataFrame(data={"end_bin": [6, 8, 10, 2, 3, 2, 2]})
    count_ser = _df.value_counts()
    _df["datasample"] = _df["end_bin"].replace(count_ser)
    _df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but it looks like you want the size per group:

```
df['datasample'] = df.groupby('end_bin')['end_bin'].transform('size')
```

Output:

```
   end_bin  datasample
0        6           1
1        8           1
2       10           1
3        2           3
4        3           1
5        2           3
6        2           3
```

Comment: and not forget convert to wiki

Comment: whats happens? why answered ? I am surprised.